# what's the best way to organize game modules

Tags: python, class, oop, module, game-engine

I'm writing a game and have made the 1st chapter to the end already. It has around 10 modules + the game engine. I'm not asking for a step-by-step guide, but if you could tell me where to look for info that would be great!

- can engine code access my modules somehow when if I place them in the different folder?(I want to sort them at least for different chapters in different folders)
- is there a different, better way to do the engine code?(let's say I will have 50 chapters in game, it would be around 500 modules so it will be around 1000 more lines of engine code just to import and call them which is very very bad style)

here's the engine code:

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

import module_intro
import module_house_one
import module_package_zoom
import module_house_two
import module_unboxing
import module_key_letter
import module_letter_key
import module_house_three
import module_end_game
```

class Engine(object):

```
def __init__(self, scene_map):
    self.scene_map = scene_map

def play(self):
    current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
    last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

    while current_scene != last_scene:
        next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
        current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

    current_scene.enter()
```

class Map(object):

```
scenes = {
'intro': module_intro.Intro(),
'house_one': module_house_one.HouseOne(),
'package_zoom': module_package_zoom.PackageZoom(),
'house_two': module_house_two.HouseTwo(),
'unboxing': module_unboxing.Unboxing(),
'key_letter': module_key_letter.KeyLetter(),
'letter_key': module_letter_key.LetterKey(),
'house_three': module_house_three.HouseThree(),
'end_game': module_end_game.EndGame()
}

def __init__(self, start_scene):
    self.start_scene = start_scene

def next_scene(self, scene_name):
    val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
    return val

def opening_scene(self):
    return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('intro')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, for example, this directory structure or something similar to put each chapter into the separate folder:

```
├── game
│   ├── chapter_one
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── chapter_two
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── engine.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

The `main.py` in the root folder will load all the chapters and start the game, it can look this way:

```
import game.chapter_one.main
import game.chapter_two.main
from game.engine import Engine, SceneMap

print("Starting the engine...")
a_map = SceneMap()
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

And the `Scene` objects can automatically register inside the `SceneMap`, so you don't have to do this manually, for example the `game.chapter_one.main.py`:

```
from ..engine import SceneMap

class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        print('Enter chapter 1')

SceneMap.register('intro', Scene)
```

and `game.chapter_two.main.py`:

```
from ..engine import SceneMap

class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        print('Enter chapter 2')

SceneMap.register('chapter 2', Scene)
```

The `SceneMap` can look like this:

```
class SceneMap(object):

    scenes = OrderedDict()

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name, map_fn):
        cls.scenes[name] = map_fn
```

The rest of your logic can be similar to what you have now (each scene returns the next scene to play).

Or, you can simplify it even more and rely on the chapters import order in the `main.py`.

So if you swap import of the chapter_one / chapter_two in the `main.py`, they will be played in backwards order.
See the full example of this approach [here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/python-game-structure).